# Get file size by ExtJS

Tags: file, extjs

how can I get size of a specific file by ExtJS, without using ActiveXObject (as recommended at some website), because my program just only run on Firefox?
Thank you so much!
(More detail: the file I want to get size in on my local, not on remote server)

Comment: Local file or file on some remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs in a sandbox, without extensions like ActiveX you are not allowed access to the file system.

Comment: I see many websites can check the size of the file I'm going to upload to their server. If the file is too big, do they upload to server first and calculate the size then return message for client? Maybe it is not good, at least in performance of that website. So I think, they have some ways to do this checking... Using ActiveX is easy to be blocked at some browsers, and it's not friendly to "non-IE-based" browsers. Thanks!

Comment: As I understood, they upload file and size to the server. When I said ActiveX, I meant any extension type, ActiveX, Flash etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Flash object. Have a look into [SWFUload](http://swfupload.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I just want to use pure JavaScript or ExtJS.